# Pandas Dataframe looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm stuck with the code below. Basically, I am looping through the first column of 2 dataframes with the loop variables 'analyticalname' and 'fedbatchname'. If these two variables find  a match in each dataframe, then I want to access that element of the dataframe based on the value of the loop variable. When I run the code, however, I get a key error that originates at the line after the if statement. In essence, I am asking how to access an element of a dataframe based on a loop variable. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
analyticaldata = pd.read_csv('SE-HPLC.csv', usecols = ['Sample ID','% 
Aggregate','% Monomer','% Fragment']) #loading data into pandas DataFrame
fedbatchdata = pd.read_csv('Culture Day Sheet.csv',usecols = 
['RUN_NUMBER','% Aggregate','% Monomer','% Fragment'])

for analyticalname in analyticaldata['Sample ID']: #for each element in 
first column of SE-HPLC worksheet
for fedbatchname in fedbatchdata['RUN_NUMBER']: #for each element in first column of Culture Day worksheet
    if analyticalname == fedbatchname: #if any of the names match
        fedbatchdata.ix[fedbatchdata.fedbatchname,'% Aggregate'] = analyticaldata[analyticalname]['% Aggregate']
        fedbatchdata.ix[fedbatchdata.fedbatchname,'% Monomer'] = analyticaldata.ix[analyticalname,'% Monomer']                  
        fedbatchdata.ix[fedbatchdata.fedbatchname,'% Fragment'] = analyticaldata.ix[analyticalname,'% Fragment']
```

EDIT: Here is some sample data for both dataframes, I apologize for leaving that out. The fedbatch dataframe is meant to be empty, I am trying to copy the values from the analytical dataframe into the fedbatch dataframe.

```
Analytical dataframe:
SAMPLE_ID:    % Aggregate    % Monomer    % Fragment
A               2             4             1.5
B               1             4             6
C               5             5             2.1
D               3             7.1           10

Fed Batch Dataframe:
RUN_NUMBER:    % Aggregate    % Monomer    % Fragment
B                                        
A                                                                                   
C
D
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample? It looks like need `analyticaldata.merge(fedbatchdata, left_on=['Sample ID'], right_on=['RUN_NUMBER'])`

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52817593/edit) it to question.

Comment: Would I have to merge the two dataframes just to simply access an element of a dataframe? I also don't understand how to add sample data, since it is in excel and when I paste the cells, it loses the excel format

Comment: Check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So `analyticaldata.merge(fedbatchdata, left_on=['Sample ID'], right_on=['RUN_NUMBER'], how='left')` working?

Comment: @jezrael Does it work? Where did you add that line of code?

Comment: Use my code after `fedbatchdata = pd.read_csv('Culture Day Sheet.csv',usecols = 
['RUN_NUMBER','% Aggregate','% Monomer','% Fragment']`,  code from `for analyticalname in analyticaldata['Sample ID']:` to end should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with rename column for avoid it in output `DataFrame` with select only column `RUN_NUMBER` from `fedbatchdata`:

```
df = (fedbatchdata[['RUN_NUMBER']]
                    .merge(analyticaldata.rename(columns={'Sample ID':'RUN_NUMBER'}), 
                          on=['RUN_NUMBER'], 
                          how='left'))
print (df)
  RUN_NUMBER  % Aggregate  % Monomer  % Fragment
0          B            1        4.0         6.0
1          A            2        4.0         1.5
2          C            5        5.0         2.1
3          D            3        7.1        10.0
```

Comment: The code would work if the values in the RUN_NUMBERS and SAMPLE_ID's were in the same order, but they are not, so I believe I have to loop through the column to find matches, then copy the data, no?

Comment: I am getting another error:     KeyError: 'RUN_NUMBER'. Any suggestions @jezrael

Comment: What is `print (fedbatchdata.columns)` ?

Comment: This is what the complier is giving me: Index(['RUN_NUMBER', '% Aggregate', '% Monomer', '% Fragment'], dtype='object')

Comment: @A.P - I see problem, need `'SAMPLE_ID'` changed to `'SAMPLE ID'`

Comment: It still gives me the same KeyError even after I changed SAMPLE_ID to SAMPLE ID

Comment: What is `print (analyticaldata.columns)` ?

Comment: This is what the complier gives me when I enter print (analyticaldata.columns): Index(['Sample ID', '% Aggregate', '% Monomer', '% Fragment'], dtype='object')

Comment: So need `SAMPLE ID` changed to `Sample ID`

Comment: Thank you! The code ran, but I do not see any changes in the csv file, do you know anything about that?

Comment: Last need `df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I learned a lot about csv and pandas!